# moving paragraph up/down (without copy / paste)

Tags: vba, ms-word

In word I am looking for a keyboard short cut which allows me to move the paragraph in which my cursor currently is one paragraph/line up or down.

I am new to VBA etc, but found this

```
Sub OutlineMoveUp()
    Selection.Range.Relocate wdRelocateUp
End Sub
```

This comes pretty close to what I am looking for, but seems to move the paragraph up according to its position in the outline structure (what can become rather confusing). I just want to move it one paragraph/line up or down (also irrespective of its formatting).

(RStudio offers this nice feature where you can simply move selected text lines without copy-pasting; I am looking for the equivalent in word).

many thx.

Answer (score 0):

The `Relocate` method is designed to work in Outline mode [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192827.aspx). Try the `Move` method instead:

```
Selection.Range.Move Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=-1
```

You may need to adjust Count to get the effect you desire --- if -1 doesn't work, try -2, etc.

Comment: many thanks. but unfortunately the command doesn't have any impact. cursor doesn't move, let alone the active paragraph/line.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to move the cursor without moving any text?

Comment: sorry if i am unclear. i want to move the paragraph in which the cursor is currently located. In many cases   "Selection.Range.Relocate wdRelocateUp" is doing this, but there are cases where the 'active' paragraph doesn't move just one line up / down, but apparently an entire level in the document structure (although I haven't fully understood the pattern behind it). I wonder whether it depends on how the active paragraph is formated. If the active paragraph is e.g. part of a list/enumeration, the entire list-bloc is moved (but I only want to move the line/paragraph in which my cursor is).

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be cleaner using cut/paste but try this:

```
Sub Test_NewP()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim CurR As Word.Range
    Dim NewP As Word.Paragraph
    Dim IndexP As Long

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    If doc.ActiveWindow.View = wdOutlineView Then
        MsgBox "This program doesn't work in outline view --- please switch to another view", vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set CurR = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
    IndexP = doc.Range(0, CurR.End).Paragraphs.Count
    Set NewP = doc.Paragraphs.Add(doc.Paragraphs(IndexP - 1).Range)
    NewP.Range.Text = CurR.Text
    CurR.Delete

    Set NewP = Nothing
    Set CurR = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

This likely won't reliably manage formatting, but you could add code to fix that.

Hope that helps.